# My swift based Mac OS app crashes on launch on other machines

Tags: swift, macos

I've created my first relatively simple Swift Mac OS app, it works fine on my development machine when running inside of Xcode and just natively outside as well. However when I run it on any other Mac, it crashes on launch with:

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
```

The other systems I've tried it on are running OS X 10.10, but in my project I've specifically targeted 10.10 for the build. Because the app runs fine on my machine, my initial thoughts are focused on code signing, but I've run the Archive command through Xcode and done the complete bundle validation with no probs. Any thoughts on next steps to try?

Comment: Can you provide the whole crash log in a pastebin or something? What happens if you launch the app with the debugger attached (`lldb <path to app>` and then type `process launch`). Another question, are you loading any files while starting your app?

Comment: You are the greatest! I didn't know how to invoke the debugger on my non-dev machine. I was immediately able to see the problem. I load some saved settings from a plist file, which of course is blank on the newly run machine.

Comment: I'll put it into an answer I suppose that way you can accept it and close the question. Glad to help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend that you attach the debugger to the application on your non-dev machine. This can be achieved by running `lldb <path to app>` and then `process launch` when the prompt is ready again. This will work as a standard debugger and should help you understand your error more completely and debug your issue.

There is no catch all for this sort of issue as to why it wouldn't run on another machine and so using the debugger to get information on the issue is the best choice in this situation.